# Is there a way to retrieve latest success dag run intervals without considering dags with skipped tasks?

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

I noticed the airflow variable {{ prev_data_interval_end_success }} can return intervals of a dag with skipped tasks.
However, I need the start/end datetime of the latest "complete" successful dag run (without any skipped task).

I was thinking of an implementation using methods such as get_task_instance but I guess there is cleaner way to do this